# My Fullstack app is having issues after being deployed with Digital Ocean

Tags: django, deployment, cloud, digital-ocean, react-fullstack

So I developed fullstack application which has Django for backend and React for frontend. I am using Digital Ocean as host for my Django project and Railway for my React project. Locally everything works perfectlly but once I deployed it, thats where it started giving some errors.

I am new to DevOps and deploying projects in general so bear with me.

I checked my deploy loggs and everything seems to be in order, my url is also correct, which points to my digital ocean server app and works fine I tested it with postman. To give you an example of the issue , user creates a message and then after its done it redirects him to the home page. Instead of seeing the message on home dashboard, its basically empty. Then when I navigate away and come back to home page message is there, but then when I do navigate away and come back again to home page message is gone.

So I have this really weird error which I really dont understand why is it occouring. So I am turning to stackoverflow community for help. Could it be because of plan package that I have on digital ocean? Like memory cap or something like that?

I btw tested my railway frontend app while running my backend locally and it works perfectly so thats how I know that the issue def lies in digital ocean part.

Any feedback on this is appreciated!

I also apologize in advance if there are any information missing but am not really sure what else to add, all the logs are fine.